# Apache Spark - Parquet / Snappy compression error

Tags: java, apache-spark, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a dataframe from an oracle table which I am attempting to write into Parquet format with Snappy compression locally.

Works fine if I save as CSV, but hitting this error when attempting to save as Parquet.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I
```

Snappy libraries are already in my classpath, this has worked for other source types (flat files).

What can I do to resolve?

Stack trace below:

```
2017-05-19 08:10:37.398  INFO 7740 --- [rker for task 0] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool  : Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
2017-05-19 08:11:45.482 ERROR 7740 --- [rker for task 0] org.apache.spark.util.Utils              : Aborting task
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(Native Method) ~[snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:na]
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.maxCompressedLength(Snappy.java:376) ~[snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCompressor.compress(SnappyCompressor.java:67) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.compress(CompressorStream.java:81) ~[hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.finish(CompressorStream.java:92) ~[hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$BytesCompressor.compress(CodecFactory.java:112) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore$ColumnChunkPageWriter.writePage(ColumnChunkPageWriteStore.java:89) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:152) ~[parquet-column-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.accountForValueWritten(ColumnWriterV1.java:113) ~[parquet-column-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.write(ColumnWriterV1.java:205) ~[parquet-column-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$MessageColumnIORecordConsumer.addBinary(MessageColumnIO.java:347) ~[parquet-column-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetWriteSupport$$makeWriter$9.apply(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:169) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetWriteSupport$$makeWriter$9.apply(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:157) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetWriteSupport$$writeFields$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:114) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetWriteSupport$$consumeField(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:422) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetWriteSupport$$writeFields(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:113) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:104) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport.consumeMessage(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:410) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport.write(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:103) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport.write(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:51) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:121) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:123) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:42) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.writeInternal(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:42) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:245) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193) [spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129) [spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128) [spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) [spark-core_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) [spark-core_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322) [spark-core_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
2017-05-19 08:11:45.484  INFO 7740 --- [rker for task 0] o.a.p.h.InternalParquetRecordWriter      : Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 13,812,677
2017-05-19 08:11:45.499  WARN 7740 --- [rker for task 0] org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil            : Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Dev\edi_parquet\GMS_TEST\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20170519081036_0000_m_000000_0\.part-00000-193f8835-6505-4dac-8cb6-0e8c5f3cff1b.snappy.parquet.crc]: it still exists.
2017-05-19 08:11:45.501  WARN 7740 --- [rker for task 0] org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil            : Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Dev\edi_parquet\GMS_TEST\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20170519081036_0000_m_000000_0\part-00000-193f8835-6505-4dac-8cb6-0e8c5f3cff1b.snappy.parquet]: it still exists.
2017-05-19 08:11:45.501  WARN 7740 --- [rker for task 0] o.a.h.m.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter   : Could not delete file:/C:/Dev/edi_parquet/GMS_TEST/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20170519081036_0000_m_000000_0
2017-05-19 08:11:45.504 ERROR 7740 --- [rker for task 0] o.a.s.s.e.datasources.FileFormatWriter   : Job job_20170519081036_0000 aborted.
```

Comment: are you appending your output?

Comment: No, just saving a full dataframe using: df.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)  method.    Turns out the issue was local to  the Windows machine I was testing on. Works fine on Linux environment....

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to an incompatibility between the *snappy-java* version that is required by parquet and *spark/hadoop*

We faced same issue for spark 2.3 on cloudera.

---

Solution which worked for us is downloading [snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.2.6/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar) and placing it in Sparks's jar folder solves the issue.

This include replacing snappy-java jar on all nodes where spark is installed.

---

you can find Spark's jar folder at following  location :

- Cloudera : */opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-{spark-cloudera-version}/lib/spark2/jars*
- Hdp : */usr/hdp/{hdp version}/spark2/jars*